# Convert pandas TimeStamp with identifier to string

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I have a string which is a combination of a date and an identifier, e.g. `2021-11-23-22`. I am using `pandas` to read a JSON to a `df`, and ultimately iterating through it to reate a csv file. I need the literal string above preserved, but `pandas` converts it to `2021-11-23 22:00:00`.

As an example:

```
import pandas as pd
# to simulate conversion it's already doing
exp_id = pd.to_datetime('2021-11-23-22') 
print(exp_id)
```

returns

```
2021-11-23 22:00:00
```

I would like it to return `2021-11-23-22`, so I need to convert the pre-generated `TimeStamp` to a string.

I have tried `str(exp_id)`, but this does not work.

I have also tried

```
exp_id.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%X')
```

but this returns the string `2021-11-23-22:00:00`. How can I convert this?

Comment: are all the ids between 0 and 23?

Comment: No, they could run from 0-infinity, but will like be less than 1000.

Comment: @nikeros - I hadn't thought to test it for higher numbers yet. When it's something like `2021-11-23-100`, pandas doesn't even try to convert it to a TimeStamp. But I need a way to handle this when even the first instance is less than 24.

Comment: shouldn't you set `convert_dates=False` in the `read_json` command and then manage as you wish? It does sound you need to keep both the date and the id, but at least suppressing the date conversion would avoid you ending up in a funny state

Comment: That doesn't seem to do anything. It's still converted to a TimeStamp.

Comment: Ah, the issue was that it was an index, so I had to do `convert_axes=False`